# Rendering templates in a Go Fiber application

Tags: go, templates, render, fibers

Does anyone have good examples of gofiber and templates ?

I am trying to display a list of videos through go fiber Html templates

Here is my Go code (entity) :

```golang
type Video struct {
    Id          int    `json:"id"`
    Title       string `json:"title"`
    Description string `json:"description"`
    VideoUrl    string `json:"description"`
    Link        string `json:"description"`
}

var videos = []*Video{
    {
        Id:          1,
        Title:       "Podcast #1",
        Description: "Here I discuss about stuff",
        VideoUrl:    "foo.m3u8",
        Link:        "videos/foo",
    },
    {
        Id:          2,
        Title:       "Podcast #2",
        Description: "Still talking",
        VideoUrl:    "bar.m3u8",
        Link:        "videos/bar",
    },
}
```

Here is my Go code (controller):

```golang
func main() {
    // Fiber instance
    app := fiber.New(fiber.Config{
        Views: html.New("./views", ".html"),
    })

    // Serve static assets
    app.Static("/", "./public", fiber.Static{
        Compress: true,
    })

    // Routes
    app.Get("/", index)

    // Start server
    log.Fatal(app.Listen(":3000"))
}

// Handler
func index(c *fiber.Ctx) error {
    return c.Render("index", fiber.Map{
        "Videos": videos,
    })
}
```

Here is my pseudo HTML :

```html
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <video-js id={{.Id}} class="vjs-default-skin my-tuby-video" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="268">
    <source src="{{.VideoUrl}}" type="application/x-mpegURL">
    </video-js>
    <script>
    var player = videojs({{.Id}});
    </script>
    
    <h2>{{.Title}}</h2>
    <p>{{.Description}}</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#">{{.Link}}</a></p>
</div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
```

Also how to I repeat this bit of HTML for each videos in my list ?

Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: I added the part where I put the videos in the map. I am really unsure about what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

As Cerise Limon commented :

```golang
{{range .Videos}}
<div class="col-lg-4">
    <video-js id={{.Id}} class="vjs-default-skin my-tuby-video" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="268">
    <source src="{{.VideoUrl}}" type="application/x-mpegURL">
    </video-js>
    <script>
    var player = videojs({{.Id}});
    </script>
    
    <h2>{{.Title}}</h2>
    <p>{{.Description}}</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-secondary" href="#">{{.Link}}</a></p>
</div><!-- /.col-lg-4 -->
{{end}}
```

Did the trick.